# Finding norm of vector using hmatrix in haskell

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell and am having trouble with
using the hmatrix library. I want to write some simple code
to compute the [eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) using the [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) method.
I start with:

```
c = fromList [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]::Vector Double
n = norm2 c
```

Which creates a vector c and finds the 2-norm of the vector.

Multiplication with `c`:

```
c * 2 (Works)
c * 0.5 (Works)
c * pi (Works)
c * n (Error)
```

I checked that:

```
>:t pi
pi :: Floating a => a
>:t n
n :: Double
```

The problem is with the types but I do not know how to get
around it.

Would I need to define my own `(/)` function in this case?

**Update:**
The error I obtain from ghci:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Vector Double'
            with actual type `Double'
In the second argument of `(*)', namely `n'
In the expression: c * n
In an equation for `it': it = c * n
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the right thing by checking the types. If we're a bit more explicit, we can see what is going on.

```
Prelude Numeric.LinearAlgebra> :t let a = 2; b = c * a in a
let a = 2; b = c * a in a :: Vector Double
```

The problem is that the type of `norm2 c` is `Double` and thus cannot be made into a `Vector Double`

Let's see the value of that polymorphic `2` from earlier.

```
Prelude Numeric.LinearAlgebra> let a = 2; b = c * a in a
fromList [2.0]
```

So instead, `n = fromList [norm2 c]`

Edit: The very same library exposes functions `scalar` and `scale` which you should look into.

Answer (score 2):

`(*)` assumes that both of its arguments have the same type:

```
(*) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

The reason that your first three multiplications worked was because in all three cases the right argument successfully type-checked as a `Vector Double`!

To see why, let's ask `ghci` what the types of those three arguments are:

```
> :t 2
2 :: Num a => a
> :t 0.5
0.5 :: Fractional a => a
> :t pi
pi :: Floating a => a
```

All three of those are valid `Vector Double`s because `hmatrix` provides the following three instances:

```
instance Num (Vector Double) where ...

instance Fractional (Vector Double) where ...

instance Floating (Vector Double) where ...
```

In other words, Haskell will transform `2`, `0.5`, and `pi` into `Vector Double`s automatically, thanks to those instances.

This explains why your last example does not type check.  `n` has type `Double`, which means that there is no chance it can ever type-check also as a `Vector Double`.